# Access django models in scrapy with split settings

Tags: python, django, scrapy, scrapyd

I am trying to use django app models within scrapy but keep getting the error "No module named myapp.apps.myscraping.myscraping.items" when trying to deploy the scrapy code to scrapyd using scrapyd-deploy.
The problem I have that I have split settings like dev, qa, production.
Based on the various links, I have added the required in the scrapy settings file but to no avail.

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
import sys
sys.path.append(BASE_DIR)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings.dev'
```

I have also tried giving the path to settings folder but to no avail.

When trying the same without split settings, it works fine.

Not to mention I am using the latest version of scrapy and scrapy.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Folder Structure:

- Project

  - manage.py
  - myapp

    - `__init__.py`
    - settings

      - dev
      - qa
      - prod
    - apps

      - `__init__.py`
      - app1

        - `__init__.py`
        - models.py
        - views.py
      - myscraping

        - `__init__.py`
        - scrapy.cfg
        - myscraping

          - `__init__.py`
          - items.py
          - pipelines.py
          - settings.py
          - spiders

            - `__init__`.py
            - dmoz.py

Regards

Comment: Can you please attach your project structure? It will help a lot.

Comment: Updated the query with folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

You miss to add pythonpath in scrapy to django project

```
# Setting up django's project full path.
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/zartch/Projects/Scrapy-Django/myweb')
```

You are appending to path BASE_DIR (/Project/myapp/apps/myscraping), You need to add only /Project